# Text is not centered with colorbox

Tags: colorbox, center

I would like to perfectly center the yellow box with the text in abstract.

Here's the code I attempted so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{acsyellow}{RGB}{255,241,204}

\usepackage{framed} 
\colorlet{shadecolor}{acsyellow}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 

\renewenvironment{abstract} 
     {
      \begin{center}
      \bfseries \vspace{-1.5cm}\vspace{0pt}
      \end{center}
      \list{}{
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{.3cm}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
      }%
      \item\relax}
 {\endlist}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} 

\title{Title}
\author{...}
\date{}
 
\begin{document}

    \vspace*{-2.5cm}{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle} 

    \begin{shaded}
        \begin{abstract}
            \textbf{Abstract}. \blindtext[1]
        \end{abstract}
    \end{shaded}

    
    \section*{Some dummy text}
       \begin{multicols}{2}
            \blindtext[10]
        \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The `abstract` environment still contained:

```
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries \vspace{-1.5cm}\vspace{0pt}
  \end{center}
```

which is unnecessary as the abstract title is in-text rather then at the top. I added `\vfill` at the start and the end of the `abstract` environment definition so that it "perfectly" centres it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{acsyellow}{RGB}{255,241,204}

\usepackage{framed} 
\colorlet{shadecolor}{acsyellow}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 

\renewenvironment{abstract} 
     {
    \vfill%
      \list{}{
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{.3cm}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
      \vfill%
      }%
      \item\relax}
 {\endlist}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} 

\title{Title}
\author{...}
\date{}
 
\begin{document}

    \vspace*{-2.5cm}{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle} 

    \begin{shaded}
        \begin{abstract}
            \textbf{Abstract}. \blindtext[1]
        \end{abstract}
    \end{shaded}

    
    \section*{Some dummy text}
       \begin{multicols}{2}
            \blindtext[10]
        \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Hope this is helpful, any questions please feel free to comment.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

First, if the whole document is typeset in the standard two column format, `multicol` might be redundant. `\twocolumn[]` directive at the beginning can change layout to two columns. You can still have the title and the abstract at the top of your document.

A title can be moved closer to the upper margin if you just negate what is set in `\maketitle`. If you want, you could also negate `\topskip` added at the top by LaTeX. Because abstract was inside `shaded` environment, any alteration of spacing affected the shaded area. I removed it in the code below.

It might also be worth setting `\parskip` to some non-zero skip if you decided to remove indentations.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}       % \patchcmd
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{acsyellow}{RGB}{255,241,204}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{acsyellow}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus 6pt minus 3pt}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{
    \list{}{
        \setlength\leftmargin{0.3cm}%
        \setlength\rightmargin{\leftmargin}%
    }%
    \item\relax}{\par\endlist}

\title{Title}
\author{...}
\date{}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 


\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
    \vspace*{-2em}%\vspace{-\topskip}%
    \maketitle
    {%
        \begin{shaded}
        \begin{abstract}
            \textbf{Abstract}. \blindtext[2]
        \end{abstract}
        \end{shaded}%
    }%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
]

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and improvements!